# How to backup existing database and website as part of a MSDeploy package?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy, one-click-web-publishing

I am researching one-click deployment with Visual Studio 2010, the current deployment process involves zipping up the contents of the IIS folder and taking a backup of the current database before completing the remaining manual deployment steps. This allows us to roll back a deployment, I need to retain the essence of this process if not the specifics.

Is there a way of automating this with MSDeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, thank you to kniemczak for posting the information about how to backup IIS and SQL Server from the command line.

- [Automating ASP.NET MVC deployments using Web Deploy](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/automating-asp-net-mvc-deployments-using-web-deploy/)
- [Web Deploy runCommand Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28WS.10%29.aspx)

It seems the following:

```
msdeploy.exe
     -verb:sync -source:runCommand='C:\Scripts\Backup.cmd' 
     -dest:auto,computername=192.168.0.1
```

Should cover my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can have MSDeploy execute a batch file that backs up the IIS directory (see [example](http://www.speedguide.net/read_articles.php?id=1547))

You can also write some SQL, put it in a .sql file, execute the SQL script in the batch file as well.  See this [example](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-backup-using-cmd-windows-command-line-backup.aspx) to at least get a start.  It is for SQL server, but if you are not using that then hopefully the database you are using has something similar.

Comment: I understand how to backup IIS, SQL Server and the files from the command line, thanks. I haven't found a way to execute an arbatary command on the server with MSDeploy.

Comment: What I was trying to state above is that you could write those commands, store them in a batch file, and then execute them as part of the deployment process.  In one of our projects we copy files to numerous locations on deployment by executing a batch file.

Comment: Your links don't actually describe the MSDeploy deployment process, just how to write scripts to backup IIS and SQL.