# Automated deploys, remote scripts, MSBuild and MSDeploy

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, web-deployment, remote-access

I'm looking for some help/direction and am generally baffled as this *must* be a common issue that people face (i.e. there should be an straight forward solution!).

I'm deploying a web site remotely using TeamCity, MSBuild and WebDeploy/MSDeploy.  I also wish to **run some scripts on the remote server that I'm deploying to.** ... **How do people generally do this?!** I just want to automate some everyday tasks remotely on ther server e.g. backing up files or similar.

Is it a case of:

- Using MSDeploy to remotely run some scripts [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213460/how-to-backup-existing-database-and-website-as-part-of-a-msdeploy-package), but then how do I transfer the scripts to the remote server as part of the automated deploy??
- Starting some sort of [PowerShell session](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315384.aspx) and remoting into the server this way?
- Some sort of ssh-ing or another way?

FYI these are the params I use for MSBuild and MSDeploy to the remote server (they work fine):

```
/p:Configuration=TeamCityLiveRelease
/p:OutputPath=bin 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:ContinueOnError="false" 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://MY.SITE:PORT/msdeploy.axd 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=my.iis.site.here 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:Username=FOO
/p:Password=baaa
```

**Ideally** I'd like to write a nice command line script and do something like (about as pseudo as it comes sorry!):

```
Log in to "http://some.server.ip" -username "user" -password "something"
run script "echo this is a remote script running"
```

Comment: I've just started using http://octopusdeploy.com/ to automate my deployments, and so far I'm pretty impressed. l think it'll do everything you need (plus it integrates with TeamCity).

Comment: Aha cool - thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think psexec is the tool you're looking for: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it seems that you can only use it on computers/servers on the same domain or network as yourself: not just to any IP (although correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I must say that I have indeed only used it on local networks, but my guess is that it should also work with remote machines, since you can use a IP-address for the host name: \\1.2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested: it is possible to use MSDeploy to carry out scripts on a remote computer (a script called `MYSCRIPT.bat` here).  If you have an admin account on the remote server then it can be done using the following arguments:

```
"c:\program files\iis\microsoft web deploy\msdeploy.exe" 
  -verb:sync 
  -source:runCommand="C:\MYSCRIPT.bat",
          waitInterval=5000,waitAttempts=1 
  -dest:auto,
        computerName=https://IP.ADDRESS.HERE:PORT/msdeploy.axd?site=IIS.SITE.NAME.HERE,userName=MYUSERNAME,password=MYPASSWORD 
  -verbose 
  -allowUntrusted
```